# percent chance logic issue/refactoring (javascript)

Tags: javascript, logic

I have an array of numbers, each one of these number represents weight. the numbers in the array is between 0 and 1, and the total of these numbers adds up to 1. So if say array[1] is 0.6 then that represents I want it to show about 60% of the time. The array itself is not known to me so I don't know these numbers, they are user input for example.

I have a solution that will work but i don't know if it is the most efficient way to do this. My solution just seems very inefficient. Here it is

- generate random number
- copy this user input array into a new array and sort it from smallest to largest
- compare the random number to numbers in this new array, so it would compare from the smallest in the array to the largest, when random number is smaller than the array number then I will store the array number into a variable say x and exit the loop
- finally, i will compare x with the original array to figure out what the index of x is in the original array

this seems like a lot of work to do, is there a simpler solution? my head does not spin that fast

EDIT - the original array is not sorted in any way

EDIT 2 - Basically I am having trouble comparing this random number to the unsorted array. I need the unsorted to stay the same which is why I created that new array in my logic

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: to find out where the random number that is generated belongs with regards to the array. it's for a rotator, and i need to find the first slide to rotate, find it by chance/weight.

Comment: Can you post some code? May help with others looking at the problem.

Comment: so if I have array[0.1, 0.5, 0.4], if my random number is 0.6 then i want the slide at 0.5 to show, if my random number is 0.3 then it should the slide that 0.4 is related to

Comment: @RubbleFord I have not written the code because I thought my method is not good, I just need to figure out the better logic then I will write my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array whose elements sum to 1, you can use the following algorithm:

1. Pick a uniformly distributed (pseuo)random number, r, between 0 and the sum of the weights.
2. For each weight,

   - If r is less than the weight, pick it and exit.
   - Otherwise subtract the weight from r, so it is now between 0 and the sum of the remaining weights.

Since r is always between 0 and the sum of the remaining weights, there is always a chance proportional to each weight that r is less than it when the loop reaches that weight.

In JavaScript:

```
var weights = [0.5, 0.15, 0.3, 0.05];
var index = weights.length - 1;  // Last by default to avoid rounding error.
var r = Math.random();

for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; ++i) {
  if (weights[i] > r) { index = i; break; }
  // The rest of the array sums to 
  // 1 - sum(weights[0]..weights[i])
  // so rescale r appropriately.
  r -= weights[i];
}
```

will give you the desired distribution.

The trick is the `r -=` which makes sure that `r` is always between 0 and the sum of the unprocessed array elements.

You can test it at http://jsfiddle.net/KdKdb/

Comment: I don't understand this logic, could you explain a bit?

Comment: I don't understand it as good as you do but I can see how it works, thank you